# Create type that would infer properties it needs to pick from another type from function type parameters

Tags: typescript

Here's a [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-sky-yycgos?file=/src/Form.tsx)

I have a type

```js
children: ({ register, formState }: Pick<UseFormReturn<T>, 'register' | 'formState') => ReactNode;
```

And I want to make it work with any parameters as long as they exist on type UseFormReturn. It needs to infer what parameters to pick based on the defined function parameters.

So for example if I wanted to add a parameter to function declaration type

```js
children: ({ register, controller, formState }) .....
```

I want parameters type definition to change accordingly without the need of manually editing type to

```js
...Pick<UseFormReturn<T>, 'register' | 'formState' | 'controller')...
```

I tried doing this

```js
children: <K>({ register, formState }: Pick<UseFormReturn<T>, UseFormReturn<T>[K]>) => ...
// and this
children: <K extends keyof UseFormReturn<T>>({ register, formState }: Pick<UseFormReturn<T>, UseFormReturn<T>[K]>) => ...
// and this
children: <K>({ register, formState }: Pick<UseFormReturn<T>, Parameters[K]>) => ...
```

but couldn't make it work.

Please help me out guys

Comment: That's not a playground, it's a codesandbox link.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/mb0ZEw) is using the TypeScript Playground.  Either way, the code here seems to depend heavily on React.  Is that necessary?  If so, you should probably tag the question as such.  If not, you should consider removing your example's dependence on it.  As it stands now I'm not going to touch it because I'm not a React expert. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz thanks for replying. You can play around in this sandbox so I see no difference calling it sandbox or playground. 
Even though the example is in react, you don't have to know react. Question is about typescript, you can think of react component as a function